# Drawing a state machine from logs

Tags: command-line, logs, graphics

I have logs in the following format:

```
03/22/2011 14:45:06;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;svr_setjobstate: setting job 35707.arien.ics.muni.cz state from EXITING-RETURNSTD to EXITING-STAGEOUT (5-51)
03/22/2011 14:45:06;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;svr_setjobstate: setting job 35709.arien.ics.muni.cz state from RUNNING-PRERUN to RUNNING-RUNNING (4-42)
03/22/2011 14:45:07;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;svr_setjobstate: setting job 35708.arien.ics.muni.cz state from RUNNING-RUNNING to EXITING-EXITING (5-50)
03/22/2011 14:45:07;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;svr_setjobstate: setting job 35708.arien.ics.muni.cz state from EXITING-EXITING to EXITING-RETURNSTD (5-70)
03/22/2011 14:45:07;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;svr_setjobstate: setting job 35708.arien.ics.muni.cz state from EXITING-RETURNSTD to EXITING-STAGEOUT (5-51)
03/22/2011 14:45:08;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;svr_setjobstate: setting job 35709.arien.ics.muni.cz state from RUNNING-RUNNING to EXITING-EXITING (5-50)
```

Now, I would like to graphically reconstruct the state machine, but I'm kind of hesitating on how to approach this problem. Cutting out the transitions shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not sure how to reconstruct a graphical representation from them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not positive I know what you mean, but are you looking for something like this?

[image: Dot output]

I used [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), which takes text input files describing transitions, and figures out the graph automatically. Here's the exact command:

```
$ sed 's/-/_/g' input | gawk '
    BEGIN {print "digraph g {"}
    END {print "}"}
    match($0, /from ([^ ]*) to ([^ ]*) \((.*)\)$/, groups) {
        print groups[1] " -> " groups[2] " [label = \"" groups[3] "\"];"
    }' > output.dot
$ dot -Tpng output.dot > output.png
```

#### Explanation

- `sed 's/-/_/g' input` -- Dot doesn't like hyphens in the node name, so I converted them to underscores
- `gawk` -- Standard awk doesn't have the `match` function that gawk has; you can do the string manipulation any way you like though (e.g. perl is another good choice)

  - `BEGIN {print "digraph g {"}` -- Dot specifications start with this line (the name of the graph, "g", doesn't really matter)
  - `END {print "}"}` -- Ends the `digraph g` started in the BEGIN block
  - `match($0, /from ([^ ]*) to ([^ ]*) \((.*)\)$/, groups)` -- A regular expression that matches your log file format; it stores the results in the `groups` variable
  - `print groups[1] " -> " groups[2] " [label = \"" groups[3] "\"];"` -- Outputs a dot-compatible line (for example, `A -> B [label = "C"];` will show two nodes, A and B, with a transition between them labeled C)
- `dot -Tpng output.dot > output.png` -- Tell graphviz to convert the dot file to a PNG

#### Resulting dot file

```
digraph g {
EXITING_RETURNSTD -> EXITING_STAGEOUT [label = "5_51"];
RUNNING_PRERUN -> RUNNING_RUNNING [label = "4_42"];
RUNNING_RUNNING -> EXITING_EXITING [label = "5_50"];
EXITING_EXITING -> EXITING_RETURNSTD [label = "5_70"];
EXITING_RETURNSTD -> EXITING_STAGEOUT [label = "5_51"];
RUNNING_RUNNING -> EXITING_EXITING [label = "5_50"];
}
```

The PNG you get when running that file through `dot` is above

Comment: Thx, I realized that I was overcomplicating it in my head :-) Your answer is awesome.

Comment: That is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a tool to do exactly what you want -- generate finite state machines from logs. The tool is called Synoptic, and you can find out more about it here:
http://code.google.com/p/synoptic/